# End or redial call in flask-socketio

Tags: javascript, socket.io, chat

I make private chat and call application using flask-socketio. User A A send call request to user  BB. I want A A want end call by pressing "End Call" button. My script below:

```
    $(document).on('click','#closebutton',function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $("#sendercallwindow").hide();
            var message = $("#receivercallwindow").hide();;
            socket.emit('chat_private', {'username': $('#receiver').val(), 'message': message});
    });
```

After click close button sender window hide but receiver window not hidden. Also if receiver close window he see [object Object] as message. socket disconnect remove user from chat but not hide window.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I edited your tags to indicate that this is a JavaScript question, not Flask-SocketIO as you tagged. I don't think you have provided enough detail here, but you cannot send a `hide()` instruction from one side to the other. You have to send some message such as "hide", and then the receiving side can issue the `hide()` call when it receives this message.

Comment: Thank you Miguel Grinberg Sir. I sent using hide using var message = $("#receivercallwindow").hide(); ... but I think I should try var message = "<script>$("#receivercallwindow").hide();</script>"

Comment: I tried to explain this above. You cannot send a function or method call from one side to the other. You can only send primitive values such as strings. Send a string with the text "hide" for example, and then on the other side when you receive this text, execute the `hide` method on your window.

Comment: Thank you again Miguel Grinberg Sir. I tried to send javascript as message. But it's not working, after your suggestion I make div and make hide function inside it. After send div as message it is working... Actually my question is wrong because I don't have enough knowledge. Now I edit my question as your suggestion.

Comment: Demo of app: https://youtu.be/P5rNN5Wjp4s